# How to highlight empty RAM slots from dmidecode -t memory output?

Tags: linux, bash

when I enter the command #dmidecode - t memory the output is about ALL RAM slots.
I made a shorter output of information on the most necessary parameters:

```
dmidecode -t memory | awk '/\tDevice/{i++;print "Device "i}/\tSpeed|GB|Factor|\Device/'
```

As a result, the output looks like this:[DMIDECODE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tz5B.png)

I want to highlight the Unknown and DIMM parameters - with the color '\e[37;1;31 (white letters in a red border)

I don’t know at all how to write a loop for the output of a command ... no matter how much I racked my brains with the if / else loop .... nothing good came of it ... help ((((

UPD: @stark No colors in my output

[output your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsck9.png)

Comment: `output looks like this:DMIDECODE OUTPUT` Sooo how can I copy that output to a file on my local computer for testing? Please do not post images of text, please post text as text.

Comment: Since SO doesn't show colored text, it is perfectly appropriate to use an image in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any unknowns in my output, so I am showing how to print SODIMM in red in the output.  I also modified the awk to print the way I wanted, which is slightly different from yours.

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | awk ' {gsub("SODIMM","\033[41mSODIMM\033[0m")} /y Device/{i++;print "Device "i} /\tSpeed|\tSize|\tForm|\tNumber/'
        Number Of Devices: 2
Device 1
        Size: 4 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
Device 2
        Size: 4 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
```

I do the substitution always on the whole input line $0 before anything else.  For awk, use \033 for ESC.

Update: for your case to highlight "Unknown" it would be:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | awk ' {gsub("Unknown","\033[41mUnknown\033[0m")} /y Device/{i++;print "Device "i} /\tSpeed|\tSize|\tForm|\tNumber/'
```

Comment: No colors in my output...

Comment: I Added a UPD clause in my question with output image attached

Comment: Please run the updated version by pasting it to your bash shell and tell me if it works.